# How to save Django ModelForm data?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have created form using ModelForm but its not saving data into database.

**views.py**

```
def answer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = AnswerForm()

    return render_to_response('quiz/index.html', {'form': form, })
```

**template**

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()

class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
```

Where i was wrong ? :/

Comment: Check if your form is really valid. Does `form.is_valid()` returns True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to handle the case where the form **isn't** valid.

Comment: Can you please explain it ? :(